# Can I export/copy google docs of a user without changing his password?

Tags: google-drive, google-workspace

How can I copy/export a users Google Drive without knowing his password?  (I am system admin off course)

If I knew the password , I could use the [batch export](http://www.labnol.org/internet/download-google-docs/10784/).  But I don't want to update/change his password, as this operation should be a [stealth](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/be/USAF_B-2_Spirit.jpg/220px-USAF_B-2_Spirit.jpg) one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saariko, I think the best option here is Backupify's [Snapshot](https://www.backupify.com/free-tools/snapshot-google-apps) tool. As an admin, you can download:

> ... all the Gmail & Gchat messages, Google Drive documents, Google Calendar events, Google Contacts entries and Google Sites data from a single Google Apps user account.